# 2D FEM element with 6 DOF per node (including rotation)

Tags: finite-element

I'm writing finite element code in 3D, and I wish to connect vertical (Euler-Bernoulli) beams to a horizontal plate. The deformations of a beam are well described, but for the plate it is more difficult: for in-plane deformations of the plate I use quadrilateral elements, and for out-of-plane deformations I use Kirchhoff-Love plate theory. However, there is one degree of freedom that is missing in the plate: the one that matches the torsional degree of freedom of the beam. This would require in-plane rotation of the plate. Is there any theory about in plane rotation of a plate?

So, I would like to implement 2D elements in a 3D environment, which includes rotation in all degrees of freedom (so 6 DOFs per node). Which element type is suitable for that purpose?

Comment: Is your structure basically several flat floors connected by columns at discrete points?
You might consider simply having six DOF only at the nodes where the columns intersect the
plate and five DOF at the purely plate nodes. This will likely be easier than implementing
a general shell finite element.